# Is there a way via python to read bash/linux console output and store as a string variable?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, console

I've been developing a block of Python code that utilizes AutoDockTools to dock a downloaded protein and ligand and evaluate the maximum magnitude of the binding energies between both. The vina program that specifically docks the chemicals produces the following output in the linux console;

[image]

I'd ideally like to read every line of output from 1 to 20. Once I do so, I can easily write code to isolate the binding affinity in kcal/mol and archive the value of the largest absolute magnitude. What would be the computationally simplest way to read specific console/terminal output from a linux command line?

Comment: You can use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run a shell command through Python and catch its output. But it might be even simpler to just pipe the output from the linux command to a text file (e.g., type `my-linux-command > output_file.txt` in the shell) and open it with Python afterwards.

Comment: You can pipe the output of one program to the input of another using `|`